# Cannot export PS1 over SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, bashrc, prompt

Trying to customize shell prompt on a Ubuntu 18 LTS server over SSH.

On the server, the `.profile` sources `.bashrc` correctly, and `.bashrc` has `force_color_prompt=yes` uncommented. The prompt is not colored.

Tried setting it manually. It does not export:

```
user@ubuntu ~ $ export PS1="[ ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u is awesome: \w ]\\$ "
user@ubuntu ~ $ echo $PS1
\u@\h \w \$
```

But as root it works fine:

```
user@ubuntu ~ $ sudo su
root@ubuntu:/home/user# export PS1="[ ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u is awesome: \w ]\\$ "
[ root is awesome: /home/user ]#
```

What is going on?

Comment: Perhaps your ordinary user's login shell is not bash?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND`. Ideally, show us the entire contents of your `~/.bashrc`. Also show us the output of `ps -p $$` as your regular user. @steeldriver are there any shells that accept the `foo=bar` syntax for variables and don't support `PS1`? [It's defined](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_03) by POSIX for `sh` so I would be very surprised to find an sh-like shell that doesn't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked `$PROMPT_COMMAND` as advised by @terdon:

```
user@ubuntu ~ $ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
__git_ps1 "\u@\h \w" "$(__drush_ps1 "[%s]") \\\$ "
```

Then looked harder at `.bashrc` and found:

```
# Include Drush prompt customizations.
if [ -f "/home/user/.drush/drush.prompt.sh" ] ; then
    source /home/user/.drush/drush.prompt.sh
fi
```

Drush was setting its own `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, apparently instead of `PS1`. Not sure how `PS1` gets overwritten by this, but it does. Commenting out Drush's superfluous customization makes the problem go away. Thanks to @terdon.